# Application . Startup Path is not working vb.net

Tags: vb.net, reference

I used this Code:

```vb
Dim Path As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Main_Master_VB.xls"
```

...in a VB.NET application and it worked very well. But when I used it in another VB.NET application with the same references, it did not work. It resulted in the following error:

> Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

What is the missing reference?

Comment: What kind of application is *the other vb.net application*? Not WinForms.

Comment: See whether you `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` and/or `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` available.

Comment: `Application` is the `System.Windows.Forms.Application` class, so it is obviously specific to Windows Forms. If you're not in a Windows Forms project then there is no such class and so no such property.

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to build file and folder paths from parts. `Dim filePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Main_Master_VB.xls")`. That method will always get the separators right, whether either, both or neither of the parts have separators or not. Note the more descriptive variable name, so as to avoid a name clash with the `System.IO.Path` class. It's also just better.

Comment: Given that `System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath` is a `Shared` member, if you are in a WinForms project then there's something else at play that is causing a name clash, e.g. the placement of the code or the naming of a class in your project.